# A sequence of finite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

**Question:** does there exist a strictly ascending sequence of finite groups 
$G_0<G_1<G_2<\dots $ such that for every $i \in \mathbb{N}$ there is $a_i \in G_{i+3}$ and the following two conditions are satisfied:

(i) $a_i$ centralizes $G_{i-1}$ in $G_{i+3}$;

(ii) $G_{i+3}=\langle G_i, a_i G_i a_i^{-1} \rangle$.

*Remark:* taking $G_i=Sym(d_i)$ for some increasing sequence of integers $(d_i)$ with the evident embedding $Sym(d_i) \hookrightarrow Sym(d_{i+1})$ does not seem to work.

Comment: @Ashot: $i+1,i+2$ are missing on purpose? If you replace $i+3$ by $i+1$, the example exists?

Comment: I think in that case, $G_{i}=S_{i}$ and $a_{i}=(i i+1)\in G_{i+1}$ would work.

Comment: @Mark; yes, $i+3$ is important. As David Cohen notices symmetric groups give an example when $i+3$ is replaced by $i+1$.

Comment: Just an idea: Try to use the regular embedding of $G$ into $\mathop{Sym}(G)$ given by the right multiplication of $G$ on itself.

Given $U < H \le G$ with $U \cap \mathrm{Z}(H) = 1$, you need to show the existence of an element $a\in \mathop{Sym}(G)$ with $\langle H, H^a\rangle = \mathop{Sym}(G)$ that centralizes $U$.

Comment: @jp: in this case $U$ will act freely on G, so it may not be easy to see that an element centralizes $U$ just looking at the action... 

Comment: Given a set $\{g_x : x \in G/U\}$ of coset representatives of $U$ in $G$ (i.e., $G = \bigcup g_x U$), you can view an element $a$ acting on the set $G/U$ as element of $\mathop{Sym}(G)$ *centralizing* $U$ by defining $(g_x u)^a := g_{x^a} u$.

Comment: To get an idea what you can do with these regular embeddings, take for example a look at: Marianna Dalle Molle, *Sylow Subgroups Which Are Maximal in the Universal Locally Finite Group of Philip Hall*, Journal of Algebra 215, 229-34 (1999)

The first hit on google when searching for the name of the paper in quotation marks gives you a link to the pdf (from sciencedirect.com to ac.els-cdn.com)

Comment: @jp: thanks, now I understand what you meant. Unfortunately in this case it may be difficult to check that $H$ and $H^a$ generate $Sym(G)$ (in fact if the index $|G:H|$ is even, then they can generate at most $Alt(G)$).

Comment: Just replace $\mathop{Sym}$ by $\mathop{Alt}$ in all my statements above. Proving $\langle H, H^a\rangle = \mathop{Alt}(G)$ for a well-chosen $a$ will be some work for sure. Do you need really $i+3$ in your statement or could you replace it by $i+2$?

Comment: @jp: yes, $i+2$ for some reason is not enough.

Comment: The idea with the regular embedding does not work, since $U$ is a block for $H$ as well as for $a$ in the action on $G$ showing that $\langle H, a\rangle$ is not primitive on $G$.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently such sequences do exist. For example, one can take $G_i:=Alt(5^i)$ for $i=0,1,2,\dots$, where the embedding $\gamma_i: G_i \to G_{i+1}$ is the diagonal embedding of $Alt(5^i)$ into $Alt(5^{i+1})$ (i.e., if $\sigma \in Alt(5^i)$ then $\gamma_i(\sigma)(1)=\sigma(1)$,  $\dots$, $\gamma_i(\sigma)(5^i)=\sigma(5^i)$, $\gamma_i(\sigma)(5^i+1)=\sigma(1)$, $\dots$, $\gamma_i(\sigma)(2\cdot 5^{i})=\sigma(5^i)$,  $\gamma_i(\sigma)(2\cdot 5^i+1)=\sigma(1)$, $\dots$

For $i \in \mathbb{N}$, the element $a_i \in G_{i+3}$ can be chosen as a certain permutation of blocks of length $5^{i-1}$, which are the orbits of $G_{i-1}=Alt(5^{i-1})$ when it is considered as a subgroup of $G_{i+3}=Alt(5^{i+3})$. This clearly implies the condition (i). The argument that $G_i$ and  $a_iG_ia_i^{-1}$ generate $G_{i+3}$ is somewhat technical. Hopefully the details will appear in the second version of http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.3317.

Comment: does it provide a group with Property FA as a limit of virtually free groups, or something of that kind?

Comment: @Yves, yes it does: a limit of virtually free groups can have (FA).